# Align text in tables in LyX

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, lyx

I want to align the text of one of my tables like this:

[image]

However, I got this:

[image]

The header of the table are centered and rotated (in case of the first column header) and the rest of the text are aligned to the left (second column) and right (rest of the columns).

So, because I'm new in this, I'm doing some bad techniques of LaTeX programming in LyX with [my LyX file](http://www.mediafire.com/view/60zijiq68bhot6c/Table2(2).lyx).

Answer (score 6):

Each cell that should be set in a different alignment compared to the rest of the column in that table needs a specific *Multicolumn* formatting. Do achieve this, right-click in the cell of interest and select *More...* > *Multicolumn*:

[image]

Now you can format the centering in the regular way using the Table toolbar:

[image]

I've also rotated the first entry by 90 degrees using the following ERT:

[image]

Your output should now resemble:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, was very useful. However, I applied the instruction `\cellcolor{lightgray}\multirow{-10}*{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\itshape Instances}}` in other table but I got this error: [link](http://postimg.org/image/4pc619psv/) I don't know if it is for the column merged in the bottom of the table. Thanks for the help

Comment: @ArCiGo: Someone [removed your LyX file](http://pastebin.com/XgNSR9vJ). Now this post will help future visitors even less. You need to add `\usepackage{graphicx}` to your LaTeX Preamble.

Comment: I didn't post my file in PasteBin (the person who edited the post removed my link from Mediadire). I'm going to edit the link of my post. 

Why in this case we don't use the package `graphicx`, but in other cases we use it?

Comment: @ArCiGo: [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) provides functionality for the inclusion of pictures, but also other scaling/rotating options. I edited the original post, and made it "never expire" on [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/). It didn't seem to work then...

Comment: Thanks for the help. Sorry for no thank you on time. I made the table. One last question: how can centralize the text of the header in the cell independent of the number of rows and number of words and that this does not protrude from the cell?

Comment: @ArCiGo: All the text in the headers are centred (except for the second), but wasn't that the main purpose of this question... and that I've answered? Perhaps you're after making the cell be of fixed-width: Right-click in cell > More... > Settings... Check Multicolumn, LaTeX argument = `p{<len>}` where you set `<len>` (say, `3cm`). This will only set the cell to format to a fixed-width `p`aragraph-style cell. If you want the contents centred as well, you need to insert an ERT containing `\centering\arraybackslash`.

Answer (score 1):

This is (almost) a solution using `xcolor`, `colortbl`, `hhline`, `makecell` and `cellspace`. However there remains in the bottom multirow a small zone that is not coloured, along the vertical line – and I don't understand. 
Nevertheless, here is the code, in the hope someone will improve it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier, heuristica}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array, multirow}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\itshape}

\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{5pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{5pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{c|Sl|*{4}{r|}}
\rowcolor{LightSteelBlue4!10!} \thead{\rotatebox{90}{Instances}} & \thead{Algorithm} & \thead{Size of the\\ solution set} & \thead{Non-dominated\\ solutions to\\ Problem 13 in \\ $ O₁ \cup O₂ $} & \thead{Non-strictly-\\outranked\\ solutions in \\$ O₁ \cup O₂ $} & \thead{Non-dominated\\ solutions to \\ Problem 15 in \\ $ O₁ \cup O₂ $} \\
     \hline
\multirowcell{2}{1} & SS-PPS & 4996 & 4819 & 10 & 0 \\
 \hhline{~|-----} \hhline{~|-----}
 & NO-ACO II & 19 & 19 & 19 & 1 \\
     \hline
\rowcolor{LightSteelBlue4!10!}\multirowcell{2}{2} & SS-PPS & 4997 & 4878 & 12 & 0 \\
 \hhline{~|-----} \hhline{~|-----}
 \rowcolor{LightSteelBlue4!10!}{} & NO-ACO II &15 & 15 & 15 & 1 \\
     \hline
  \end{tabular}%
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]